# Which is the equivalent of php drupal format_interval for javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to use with JavaScript and `Drupal.t()` the equivalent of `format_interval()`.

With PHP I would use the following code.

```
print t("!date ago", array("!date" => format_interval(time() - $lastActivity, 1)));
```

What would the equivalent in JavaScript be?

Comment: The `t` method is a Drupal text sanitizing and translating equivalent to the `t()` PHP function from Drupal core.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal doesn't implement a JS version of `format_interval()`; this is a rough (minimally tested) port:

```
Drupal.formatInterval = function(interval, granularity, langcode) {
  granularity = typeof granularity !== 'undefined' ? granularity : 2;
  langcode = typeof langcode !== 'undefined' ? langcode : null;

  var units = {
    '1 year|@count years': 31536000,
    '1 month|@count months': 2592000,
    '1 week|@count weeks': 604800,
    '1 day|@count days': 86400,
    '1 hour|@count hours': 3600,
    '1 min|@count min': 60,
    '1 sec|@count sec': 1
  },
  output = '';

  for (var key in units) {
    var keys = key.split('|'); 
    var value = units[key];
    if (interval >= value) {
      output += (output.length ? ' ' : '') + Drupal.formatPlural(Math.floor(interval / value), keys[0], keys[1], {}, { langcode: langcode });
      interval %= value;
      granularity--;
    }

    if (granularity == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }

  return output.length ? output : Drupal.t('0 sec', {}, { langcode: langcode });
}
```

Some random results using the above (they seem to match up to the PHP function as expected):

- 3643       => *1 hour 43 sec*
- 92900      => *1 day 1 hour*
- 2592000    => *1 month*
- 9331200    => *3 months 2 weeks*
- 297605232  => *9 years 5 months*

Answer (score 2):

Clives implementation is doing well. However, Drupals javascript aggregator needs to parse all javascript files for translatable strings.
As Clive uses dynamic values for Drupal.formatPlural this won't work here.

So here's another implementation with working translation:

```js
Drupal.formatInterval = function(interval, granularity) {
  granularity = typeof granularity !== 'undefined' ? granularity : 2;    
  output = '';

  while (granularity > 0) {
    var value = 0;
    if (interval >= 31536000) {
      value = 31536000;
      output += (output.length ? ' ' : '') + Drupal.formatPlural(Math.floor(interval / value), '1 year', '@count years');
    }
    else if (interval >= 2592000) {
      value = 2592000;
      output += (output.length ? ' ' : '') + Drupal.formatPlural(Math.floor(interval / value), '1 month', '@count months');
    }
    else if (interval >= 604800) {
      value = 604800;
      output += (output.length ? ' ' : '') + Drupal.formatPlural(Math.floor(interval / value), '1 week', '@count weeks');
    }
    else if (interval >= 86400) {
      value = 86400;
      output += (output.length ? ' ' : '') + Drupal.formatPlural(Math.floor(interval / value), '1 day', '@count days');
    }
    else if (interval >= 3600) {
      value = 3600;
      output += (output.length ? ' ' : '') + Drupal.formatPlural(Math.floor(interval / value), '1 hour', '@count hours');
    }
    else if (interval >= 60) {
      value = 60;
      output += (output.length ? ' ' : '') + Drupal.formatPlural(Math.floor(interval / value), '1 min', '@count min');
    }
    else if (interval >= 1) {
      value = 1;
      output += (output.length ? ' ' : '') + Drupal.formatPlural(Math.floor(interval / value), '1 sec', '@count sec');
    }

    interval %= value;
    granularity--;
  }

  return output.length ? output : Drupal.t('0 sec');
}
```